# How can I intercept a form without resulting in it being submitted twice?

Tags: jquery

I want to intercept a form, check for a condition and if it exists, prevent the default action. Otherwise, I want to pretend no such interception took place. The JavaScript looks something like this.

```
$("form").submit(function (event)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),

        type: $(this).attr("method"),

        data: $(this).serialize(),

        dataType: "html",

        async: false,

        success: function (response)
        {
            if (foo in response) // This is just pseudo code.
            {
                event.preventDefault();

                // bar
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the form is being submitted twice if `foo` is not found in `response` and I can't figure out why. I can assure you that it is a JavaScript issue. If I disable this progressive enhancement, everything works as designed.

EDIT: Adding `return false` at the end of the code is absolutely incorrectly. I stated that if `foo` is not found in `response` I want to pretend no such interception took place. That means I want the page to refresh and do whatever it was going to do.

I am already preventing the default event under very specific circumstances.

EDIT: sillyMunky and alex have touched on my issue. There is definitely a flaw in my design that I'm trying to resolve.

EDIT: I'm looking for help and I have provided code. Downgrading questions and answers without providing feedback is just plain rude.

Comment: Yeah, and I got voted down and lost reputation points for it, probably the same nazi who voted your question down instead of asking if it could be edited to clear up anything they thought was 'bad' about it.  Still happy to help.

Comment: @sillyMunky: Nazis were responsible for many deaths. You lost 2 reputation points. `!=`

Comment: @alex: again, acting on totally unfounded assumptions and just lashing out instead of dialogue. I meant this valid, legitimate meaning you find on dictionary.com:

3. Sometimes Offensive . ( often lowercase ) a person who is fanatically dedicated to or seeks to control a specified activity, practice, etc.: a jazz nazi who disdains other forms of music; tobacco nazis trying to ban smoking. 

i.e. someone who behaves as you seem to on this site.

It was you who changed it to uppercase. tut tut, misquotes an' all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are submitting the form via XHR. If so, just call [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) at the top of your [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function.

If you want to natively resubmit the form later in the `success` callback, call the form's native `submit()` event, i.e. `$('form')[0].submit()` (which won't trigger jQuery's `submit()` which would cause an infinite loop because of the rehandling of the condition).

Using `async: false` will lock the browser before the request has finished. Don't do that.

Comment: I'd have to go with this. It appears the flaw is your design, not the Javascript.

Comment: At the **top**? How is ajax request supposed to be called then? :-S

Comment: @zerkms: It will cancel the native submit of the browser, allowing the XHR time to send. It won't affect the XHR.

Comment: @alex: This works except it doesn't refresh the page on submit. I presume I'm going to have to handle it after the manual submit?

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid: Why would you want to submit the form via XHR to the exact same place and then refresh the whole page? XHR for XHR's sake?

Comment: @alex: I don't know what XHR is. The key reason is because if `foo` is found in `response` then I don't want the page to refresh.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid: [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). The *magic* of *AJAX*.

Comment: @alex: Ahh. Too many acronyms and initialisms. Well, now that you know it's not just for it's own sake, is there a better way to do it or is this it?

Answer (score 3):

Just put `return false;` in the very end of your `function (event)` body

Comment: @zerkms: This is absolutely incorrectly. You seem to have misunderstood me.

Comment: Couldn't you also do: `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @Fake Code Monkey Rashid: or may be you just have described not well enough.

Comment: @zerkms: I explained in the first 2 sentences. I want the event prevented under specific circumstances. Not all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the form is submitting by html and submitting by ajax.  I would turn the submit button into any other kind of button (so it doesn't fire off the form) and then use the ajax call (called onclick) to determine whether or not to send the form off.  If this decision depends on a server response then you have no choice but to submit it twice if the condition requires the form to be updated.

Comment: Would anyone care to comment why some idiot voted my answer down? Its a very legitimate answer, I'm a professional programmer, I have this technique deployed and it works well, across browsers too.  Leave a comment if you have misunderstood what I have said or think it is inappropriate, don't just vote down valid, intelligent contributions.

Comment: +1: I agree that this silly practice of downvoting without leaving appropriate feedback is getting out of hand. This answer certainly helped me understand something.

Comment: Well lets just ignore them then, right  ... so do you know where you're going now? If you still have problems, update the question and/or stick the offending code on pastebin ;)

Comment: I am the idiot who downvoted your answer because you suggest using a different element (besides a *submit*) to submit the form. This will leave your form unusable in an environment without JavaScript or JavaScript disabled. It is trivial to use a submit element (allowing these non JS users to use your form) whilst disabling its role as submitting the form via JavaScript to allow submission via XHR.

Comment: @alex: I upvoted him because the first sentence of his answer helped me and because he was downvoted without explanation and that helps no one. I agree with what you are saying about rendering the form unusable in an environment without JavaScript but please consider leaving a comment explaining why you have downvoted an item in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment alex.  I assumed that since his site clearly required jquery anyway, there was no point thinking about the HTML only case.  Plus, the functionality he wishes requires an active client side technology like javascript to be enabled. This does not really cut out significant numbers of visitors anymore.  It seems like you and I have both made more assumptions than we thought about his environment, I think mine were closer to his needs.
Comments are much more useful to everyone than downvotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to cancel the original request.  Also, by the time your other request is sent, it is too late to cancel the event.

Either `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the original request.